# Include interaction terms in a fixed effect model using feols

Tags: r, syntax, linear-regression, panel-data

I have a question regarding the usage of feols in the fixest package. I want to run a regression where the explanatory variable `x1` is a variable which has a panel structure, and `x2` is a time-series variable. The dependent variable `y` has a panel structure as well.

```
feols(y ~ x1 + x1*x2 | date, dat)
```

The coefficient of the interaction term `x1*x2` is of interest. But if i run the regression above, there is a warning saying the variable `x2` is removed because of collinearity.

I understand it because in the presence of the time fixed effect, any time-series variables will be collinear with the fixed effect. But i don't know why there is still such a warning even if I haven't included `x2` alone in the regression form.

I don't want to use the `i()` syntax because that will give me coefficients for each of the interaction term. Rather, i want to have only one coefficient for the interaction term which describes an average effect. Are there any suggestions?

I would highly appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not `fixest` specific but peculiar to the way `R` parses a formula.

As odd as it seems, writing `x1*x2` in a formula will include not just the `x1*x2` term, but it will also include `x1` and `x2`.

What you are looking for is, either:

- `x1:x2` which only includes the interaction (and not the variables)
- `I(x1*x2)` where `I()` tells R not to touch what's inside, so effectively adding only the interaction.

Here are some examples:

```
base = iris
names(base) = c("y", "x1", "x2", "x3", "species")

# the multiplication adds x1 and x2
head(model.matrix(y ~ x1*x2, base))
#>   (Intercept)  x1  x2 x1:x2
#> 1           1 3.5 1.4  4.90
#> 2           1 3.0 1.4  4.20
#> 3           1 3.2 1.3  4.16
#> 4           1 3.1 1.5  4.65
#> 5           1 3.6 1.4  5.04
#> 6           1 3.9 1.7  6.63

# x1:x2 only includes the product
head(model.matrix(y ~ x1 + x1:x2, base))
#>   (Intercept)  x1 x1:x2
#> 1           1 3.5  4.90
#> 2           1 3.0  4.20
#> 3           1 3.2  4.16
#> 4           1 3.1  4.65
#> 5           1 3.6  5.04
#> 6           1 3.9  6.63

# I(x1*x2): idem
head(model.matrix(y ~ x1 + I(x1*x2), base))
#>   (Intercept)  x1 I(x1 * x2)
#> 1           1 3.5       4.90
#> 2           1 3.0       4.20
#> 3           1 3.2       4.16
#> 4           1 3.1       4.65
#> 5           1 3.6       5.04
#> 6           1 3.9       6.63
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for giving this hint!! This is very helpful :)